# xpath giving wrong output in simple html dom

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape every line on this url

http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/news/archive

I've used xpath-helper to create following path:

```
//div[class='content']/table[@class='simple gamelist medium']/tbody/tr
```

this should print every line in the tbody however when i try this in simple html dom, it returns the thead with the title, date and comment. How come it does not return the tbody instead as it does in xpath helper?

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');



    function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}

    $html = str_get_html(getHTML("http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/news/archive",10));



    $table = $html->find("//div[class='content']/table[@class='simple gamelist medium']/tbody/tr",0);

    echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

The simplehtmldom library doesn't appear to support positional predicates in XPath. To get a specific row, you need to pass a 0-based index as the second parameter to `find()`.

To get the first non-header row (the second table row):

```
$table = $html->find("//div[class='content']/table[@class='simple gamelist medium']/tbody/tr", 1);
```

[working phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1b5t-picz)

<del>You XPath expression is selecting each `tr` element. If you want the whole `tbody` element, remove `/tr` from the end of the expression.

If you only want the table cells (`td`), add `/td[1]`.

If you only want the titles, add `/td[1]/a/string()`.</del>

Comment: Okay but how do i get second row? i've tried [2], but does not seem to work

Comment: what do you get from `//div[class='content']/table[@class='simple gamelist medium']/tbody/tr[2]`? No results?

Comment: that is strange. Can you add the output of your original XPath expression to your question?

Comment: output of following //div[class='content']/table[@class='simple gamelist medium']/tbody/tr ?